# How do I make it so it only prints once per occurrence per loop?

Tags: python, loops, printing

I want this to print Start and stop times so I can verify lights are going On and OFF when they should.
Example:
Light schedule
Lights ON
7:00 AM
Lights OFF
1:00 AM
Lights ON
7:00 AM
...

What I'm getting instead is
printing lights ON from 7am-1am
printing lights OFF from 1am-7am
...

```
try:
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        GPIO.output(R1,GPIO.LOW)
        if now.hour == 7:
            GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.HIGH)
            print("Lights ON")
            print(time.strftime("%-I:%M %p"))
        elif now.hour == 1:
            GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.LOW)
            print("Lights OFF") 
            print(time.strftime("%-I:%M %p"))       
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I would recommend providing clarity on the problem rather than downvoting all answers :/

Comment: Another question, do you want to infinitely keep running the while loop?

Comment: Yes. This is for an indoor vegetable garden, so it needs to run from plant to harvest.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your inputs. Do check and let me know if that works for you. I would advice for proper testing, check this on `now.minute` instead of hour. That way you can test if your loop is working properly. (just be sure to comment out the prints statements)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Updated my answer based on more clarity.

1. Assuming that `GPIO.output()` is like an on-off switch, you need to make sure that the first default setting is outside the while loop.
2. Since you want the loop to run indefinitely, you cant use `break`. If you do that however, the loop will keep updating the `GPIO` indefinitely, which you dont want either. So, I would recommending adding a flag `toggle`.
3. If `toggle==1`, the if condition is allowed to update the `GPIO` values else if can't. By default it is set to 1, so the second it encounters `now.hour==7` or `1`, it will update it. But once its done implementing the code, it sets it to `0` again. This prevents it from continuously updating the `GPIO` values.
4. Now, when the hour changes, you want the `toggle` to go back to 1, so that it can check the hour and update if needed. This is done by storing the value of the previous hour in `lasthour` and checking it as part of a `elif` condition.
5. Lastly, you use `time.strftime`. Instead, you can simply use `now.strftime` to get the time printed in the right format.

```
import datetime

testtime = datetime.datetime(2020,1,6,7)

try:
    #GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.LOW)
    toggle = 1
    lasthour = 0
    
    while True:  
        now = testtime
        
        if now.hour == 7 and toggle==1:
            #GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.HIGH)
            print("Lights ON")
            print(now.strftime("%-I:%M %p"))
            lasthour = now.hour
            toggle=0
            
        elif now.hour == 1 and toggle==1:
            #GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.LOW)
            print("Lights OFF") 
            print(now.strftime("%-I:%M %p"))
            lasthour = now.hour              #<- Save last hour of updatre
            toggle=0                         #<- Set toggle to 0
        
        elif lasthour != now.hour:           #<- If change in hour
            toggle=1                         #<- Set toggle to 1
            
        print('_________running_________; toggle ->', toggle) #Comment this
finally:
    print("out of while loop")
    #GPIO.cleanup()
```

```
Lights ON
7:00 AM
_________running_________; toggle -> 0
_________running_________; toggle -> 0
_________running_________; toggle -> 0
_________running_________; toggle -> 0
_________running_________; toggle -> 0
_________running_________; toggle -> 0
_________running_________; toggle -> 0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    try:
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        GPIO.output(R1,GPIO.LOW)
        if now.hour == 7 and now.minute == 0:
            GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.HIGH)
            print("Lights ON")
            print(time.strftime("%-I:%M %p"))
        elif now.hour == 1 and now.minute == 0:
            GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.LOW)
            print("Lights OFF") 
            print(time.strftime("%-I:%M %p"))       
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

You have to check the minutes too, otherwise it will print Lights ON from 7:00 till 7:59 and the same with lights off.

Also, be aware of the while loop. The way you coded it, it will run forever unless you stop it manually.

Comment: This is for an indoor vegetable garden, so I need it to run from plant to harvest.